# How do I change the background color of a form text_area?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, erb

The background color of my blog is blue and I want to make the background color of my `text_area` form white but currently the `text_area` form is the same blue as the background of my blog.

With the code below the `text_field` background is white and the submit button background is also white, but the `text_area` background is still blue.

---

---

html.erb code:

```
<div class="post">
  <%= form_for @post do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %><br>
    <%= f.label :post %> <br>
    <%= f.text_area :post, size: "95x20"  %><br>
  <%= f.submit %>
<%end%>
</div>
```

css code:

```
.post input {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply the background to the `textarea` element, for example:

```css
.post textarea {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```